# Show a hidden field with simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a hidden field as such:

```
<%= f.input :authentication, label: 'Authentication Password', as: :hidden %>
```

I want to show the hidden field when the admin radio button is clicked:

```
<%= f.input :account_type , as: :radio_buttons, :checked => 'Student', collection: ['Student', 'Admin'], wrapper: :vertical_radio_and_checkboxes %>
```

How would I do so?

I have tried using

```
$('#user_authentication').show();
```

But this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove as: hidden and use
`$('#user_authentication').hide();` when DOM is loaded.